# How do you manually download the MFC120D.i386.pdb

Tags: debugging, mfc

How I manually download symbols for MFC12? Specifically mfc120d.i386.pdb?

Comment: Check Visual Studio _Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols_.  Do you have the **Microsoft symbol Server** checked as a symbol file location?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this machine is not connected to the internet and cannot be connected to the internet. Is there a way to have offline install of the symbols.

Comment: If you can't download, how are you expecting to make symbols available?  From a disk?

Comment: I know that Microsoft has some symbols available via msi packages. However I have not be able to find the mfc symbols for visual studio 2013.

Comment: Since you posted this question, I'm assuming that you do have a machine, that is connected to the internet. Download the symbols from that machine, and copy them to the machine, where you need the symbols. [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) can download [symbols](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#7_symbols) for specific modules.